# Is there an implicit execution context inside of ApplicationLoader

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I'm thinking of creating my own custom ApplicatoinLoader for my Play application.

Is there a custom execution context hidden here somewhere?

Does this mean inside of my custom application loader, I can wire up my custom akka actors and not have to create a custom execution context?

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/core/play/src/main/scala/play/api/ApplicationLoader.scala#L240

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That execution context is inherited from `BuiltInComponents`:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/508159092cdd27c56d6c3ca1cc32f0cd1bc86c08/core/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Application.scala#L225

Which inherits it from `AkkaComponents`:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/508159092cdd27c56d6c3ca1cc32f0cd1bc86c08/core/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/concurrent/Akka.scala#L110

As you can see, the execution context is just the actor systems default dispatcher.